# how to make Doctrine_Expression ( doctrine 1.2 ) try to get last 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-1.2

I try to make this query with doctrine 1.2:

```
 $q->where('date > ?', 
             new Doctrine_Expression('DATE_SUB(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 7 DAY)'));
```

but it's not return me any results.

any idea ?

thanks

Comment: I assume you have checked all this, but for completeness' sake - is `date` a DATETIME column? Do you have data that matches the criteria?

Comment: yes i check this, its work like $q->where('date > ?','2011-10-04')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't return anything is because Doctrine escapes the expression - the generated SQL is

```
WHERE (date > 'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)')
```

rather than

```
WHERE (l.action_time > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

You could force it to work like this:

```
$date = new Doctrine_Expression('DATE_SUB(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 7 DAY)');
$q->where('date > ' . $date);
```

This isn't the safest option however, as the input doesn't get escaped and isn't good practice...

Comment: I am using Doctrine2 with Symfony2, I tried your above suggestion but it says \Doctrine_Expression' not found in. Can you tell me what and how can i use Doctrine_Expression in my repository

Comment: This question is about Doctrine 1.2. Doctrine 2 is a completely different product.