# DATE_SUB and INTERVAL in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

How can i make this in Doctrine 1.2?

Comment: Does it need to run on other systems then mysql? If not you just write it as above in DQL.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this answer ?
[how to make Doctrine_Expression ( doctrine 1.2 ) try to get last 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672125/how-to-make-doctrine-expression-doctrine-1-2-try-to-get-last-7-days)

```
$date = new Doctrine_Expression('DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 30 DAY)');
$q->where('date > ' . $date);
```